# How to return a value to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return

I'm making a simple poll/survey to check where user can go to work. I went with yes or no answers. I made a point counter, so it can check user information if he answered yes then add one point. I want to make a function that displays a question and check user input instead of writing same do while loop for each question. I made an array for collecting "user points". But, the problem is that since program is jumping to loop and adding +1 point it just can't return a value to this "point array". This value is somewhere else in memory but not in array. This results to not properly working summary. It just shows everywhere 0 points to each possible work. What I've made wrong or what can I make to make it working properly?

Here's my code (I probably messed up formatting braces by copy/paste):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace Survey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //here's my Question Bank

        ArrayList QuestionList = new ArrayList();
        QuestionList.Add("1. Question");
        QuestionList.Add("2. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("3. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("4. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("5. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("6. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("7. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("8. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("9. ...");
        QuestionList.Add("10. ...");

        //here's my work list.
        ArrayList WorkList = new ArrayList();
        WorkList.Add("IT");
        WorkList.Add("Architect");
        WorkList.Add("Politician");
        WorkList.Add("Driver");
        WorkList.Add("Designer");

        //here's an array, where I want to hold "points". The higher points the more probably user will get suggestion where to work.
        int[] Work;
        Work = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        Console.WriteLine("Hi. Say 'y' if you agree or 'n' if not.");

        displayQuestion(QuestionList[0], Work[0]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[1], Work[1]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[2], Work[2]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[3], Work[3]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[4], Work[4]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[5], Work[4]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[6], Work[1]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[7], Work[2]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[8], Work[0]);
        displayQuestion(QuestionList[9], Work[3]);

        // here's calculating maximum points 
        int max;
        max = Work[0];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            if (Work[i] > max)
                max = Work[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if(Work[i]==max)
            Console.WriteLine("You can work as: " + WorkList[i]);
        }

        //Summary
        Console.WriteLine("Points as: " + WorkList[0] + " = " + Work[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Points as: " + WorkList[1] + " = " + Work[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Points as: " + WorkList[2] + " = " + Work[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Points as: " + WorkList[3] + " = " + Work[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Points as: " + WorkList[4] + " = " + Work[4]);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    //here's the PROBLEM (I think)
    public static int displayQuestion(object whichQuestion, int WorkPoints)
    {
        string answer;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(whichQuestion);
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer == "y")
            {
                WorkPoints++;
            }
        } while (answer != "y" && answer != "y");
        return WorkPoints;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a [MCVE]?

Comment: I'll try edit code

Comment: try to change your function to the following `int  displayQuestion(object whichQuestion, ref int WorkPoints)` and call it like `displayQuestion(QuestionList[0],ref Work[0])`

Comment: Thank you @SamvelPetrosov now it finally works!

Comment: @MarcinChmurowski what changes you have done that works fine????

Comment: @Llazar I've changed exactly what Samvel Petrosov said. So I added ref keyword.

Comment: I have done the same, changed the method like @SamvelPetrosov sad `displayQuestion(QuestionList[0],ref Work[0])` and the method shows error.

Comment: @Llazar you have to also add `public static int` and `ref` keyword in your arguments in function. `public static int displayQuestion(object whichQuestion, ref int WorkPoints)`.

Comment: Wow! I haven't seen an `ArrayList` in more than 10 years!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you're assigning the new score  to the return value of the **displayQuestion** Method and not using it.

```
public static int displayQuestion(object whichQuestion, int WorkPoints)
```

so a possible approach is tu use `the` ref keyword as **Samvel** said or assign the return value of the method to **work[i]**:

```
Work[0] = displayQuestion(QuestionList[0], Work[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to the following:

```
public static int displayQuestion(object whichQuestion)
{
    string answer;
    int WorkPoints = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(whichQuestion);
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "y")
        {
            WorkPoints++;
        }
    } while (answer != "y" && answer != "n");
    return WorkPoints;
    }
}
```

and then use it this way:

```
Work[0] += displayQuestion(QuestionList[0]);
```